Deleted contacts/todo items/calendar events create empty Message resource
As title says, whenever I remove a contact from my contact list, it's moved to Deleted Items folder as an empty Message resource. This message is empty and its odata type is also message. This makes it impossible to differentiate between the deleted item is a contact or message.
For an additional context, I'm working on a mail client that uses MS Graph API for managing e-mails for logged-in users.
I found similar issues on web going 4-5 years back. Is this behavior documented somewhere or is there any way to differentiate between these items?

Which endpoint do you call to remove contact from your contact list?

I am not deleting contacts from the API. I use Outlook mail client or OWA to remove the contacts or any other items.
Deleting them from any of these clients create the empty message resource. Not surprisingly; these deleted items are also visible in Deleted Items folder in those clients, but they can't be opened. Client will show a message something like "recover item to open"
